# Django textarea for 50,000,000 character data

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I've a django application that deals with large text files, up roughly 50,000,000 characters.  For a variety of reasons it's desirable to store them as a model field.

- We are using sqlite for dev and postgres for production.
- Users do not need to enter the data via any UI.
- The field does not need to be visible in the admin or elsewhere to the user.

Several questions:

- Is it practicable to store this much text in a textarea field?
- What, if any, performance issues will this likely create?
- Would using a binary field improve performance?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PostgreSQL won't care about something this size in the slightest, and it'll store it out-of-line from the main tuple in compressed form. Just make sure your app doesn't fetch it when it doesn't need that column, and make especially sure it doesn't do something stupid like `SET`ing in an `UPDATE` even when it hasn't changed, because that'll bloat the transaction logs and TOAST table unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks Craig.  I'd not known about PostgreSQL and compression.  That turns out to be a big issue.  Currently this text is being stored in files on a compressed file system.  There was concern about storing them uncompressed on an uncompressed file system. Since PostgreSQL will compress that eliminates that concern.

Comment: Depends ... PostgreSQL intentionally uses a faster, less effective compression codec that's a usually a better performance/space trade-off, and is patent-unencumbered. There've been discussions of changing it to a more cpu-costly and more effective one, but patent concerns slow things down.

Comment: Interesting.  We are still looking at a couple of alternate designs but it is likely that we'll use a custom model field derived from blob with the text compressed on storage and decompressed when accessed.  We're looking at blobs as opposed to textfield to avoid having to encode to accommodate textarea character issues. Since the data is generally write once/read once we're not especially concerned about cpu-cost for compression/decompression.

Answer (score 2):

Another consideration is that when you are querying that model, make sure you use [defer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.defer) on your querysets, so you aren't transferring 50MB of data down the pipe everytime you want to retrieve an object from the db.

I highly recommend storing those files on disk or S3 or equivalent in a FileField though. You won't really be able to query on the contents of those files efficiently.

Comment: Thanks Sohan.  In this application we don't actually need to query on the text file contents so that's not a concern in this case. 

In part, we are trying to avoid using file system files and the associated risk of files disconnected from the controlling DB since the text files are currently stored on a symlinked compressed file system (we've had some issues with disconnected text files that are a pain in the A.. to resolve).

Answer (score 1):

This is more related to the database you use. You use SQLite so look at the limits of SQLite:

> The maximum number of bytes in a string or BLOB in SQLite is defined
>   by the preprocessor macro SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH. The default value of this
>   macro is 1 billion (1 thousand million or 1,000,000,000).

http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Besides that, it's probably better to use a [TextField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField) in Django.

A binary field wouldn't improve performance. Binary fields are meant for binary data, and you are storing text.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation we decided to use a Django file field and **not** store the file contents in Postgresql.  Performance was the primary decision driver.  With file field we are able to query very quickly to get the underlying field file which in turn can be accessed directly at the OS level with **much higher performance** than is available if the data is stored in a Postgresql table.

Thanks for the input.  It was a big help.